# Show that if $b\mid c$ and $b > \gcd(c, d)$, then $b\nmid d$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I have no clue about how to go about this question. I feel like I need more info, but I don't know, please help.

Comment: If $b|d$ and $b|c,$  $b|(c,d)$

Comment: Suppose by contradiction that $b\mid d$. What then could you say about $\gcd(c, d) $?

Comment: b>d thus b/d<1.

Answer (score 4):

**hint**: Use proof by contradiction:

Assume $b\mid c$ and $b\gt \gcd(c, d).$

Now suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $b\mid d$.

So, if $b$ divides $c$ and $b$ divides $d$, then $b \mid \gcd(c, d).\quad$ (Why?).

But ...

Comment: It's enough to say that $b$ is a commn divisor, hence cannot exceed the *greatest* common divisor (if the latter is defined with its literal meaning).

Comment: @amWhy: needs another TU! :-)